# android setcookie

Tags: android, cookies, hostname

i am trying to set a cookie as below.

```
CookieSyncManager.createInstance(context);
CookieManager cookieManager = CookieManager.getInstance();
cookieManager.setCookie("http://wwww.mydomain.com",
                "mycookie=123"; Domain=.mydomain");
CookieSyncManager.getInstance().sync();
```

When i access a page from mydomain.com, the cookie can be retrieved. but when i try to set cookie using IP address, the page cannot retrieve the cookie.

1) is it because we can only set cookie using hostname?
2) why when i access a website using IP address, the website is still able to set and retrieve the cookie?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Its a domain name by specification:

> Domain=domain
>         Optional.  The Domain attribute specifies the domain for which the
>         cookie is valid.  An explicitly specified domain must always start
>         with a dot.

http://www.ietf.org/rfc/rfc2109.txt

Android might extract domain and path from an URL, but the domain must be a fully-qualified domain name.

Further, if you access via ip the following statement is relevant:

> Domain Selection The origin server's
>   fully-qualified host name must
>   domain-match the Domain attribute of
>   the cookie.

The answer is yes though.

Comment: hmmm.. don't really understand? meaning i can only set cookie using domain name?

Comment: Given that Android stores the cookie according to the specification; yes. You have to use a domain name. But if your domain name resolves to the same host, you will be able to read the cookie on pages addressed via IP also.